# In place insertion into list (or array)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, list-comprehension

I'm running a script in Python, where I need to insert new numbers into an array  (or list) at certain index locations. The problem is that obviously as I insert new numbers, the index locations are invalidated. Is there a clever way to insert the new values at the index locations all at once? Or is the only solution to increment the index number (first value of the pair) as I add?

Sample test code snippets:

```
original_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
insertion_indices = [1, 4, 5]
new_numbers = [8, 9, 10]
pairs = [(insertion_indices[i], new_numbers[i]) for i in range(len(insertion_indices))]

for pair in pairs:
    original_list.insert(pair[0], pair[1])
```

Results in:

```
[0, 8, 1, 2, 9, 10, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

whereas I want:

```
[0, 8, 1, 2, 3, 9, 4, 10, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: @Divakar Typo for `insertion_indices` I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Being NumPy tagged and since input is mentioned as list/array, you can simply use builtin [`numpy.insert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) -

```
np.insert(original_list, insertion_indices, new_numbers)
```

To roll out the theory as a custom made one (mostly for performance), we could use mask, like so -

```
def insert_numbers(original_list,insertion_indices, new_numbers):
    # Length of output array                               
    n = len(original_list)+len(insertion_indices)

    # Setup mask array to selecrt between new and old numbers
    mask = np.ones(n,dtype=bool)
    mask[insertion_indices+np.arange(len(insertion_indices))] = 0

    # Setup output array for assigning values from old and new lists/arrays
    # by using mask and inverted mask version
    out = np.empty(n,dtype=int)
    out[mask] = original_list
    out[~mask] = new_numbers
    return out
```

For list output, append `.tolist()`.

Sample run -

```
In [83]: original_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    ...: insertion_indices = [1, 4, 5]
    ...: new_numbers = [8, 9, 10]
    ...: 

In [85]: np.insert(original_list, insertion_indices, new_numbers)
Out[85]: array([ 0,  8,  1,  2,  3,  9,  4, 10,  5,  6,  7])

In [86]: np.insert(original_list, insertion_indices, new_numbers).tolist()
Out[86]: [0, 8, 1, 2, 3, 9, 4, 10, 5, 6, 7]
```

**Runtime test on a `10000x` scaled dataset** -

```
In [184]: original_list = range(70000)
     ...: insertion_indices = np.sort(np.random.choice(len(original_list), 30000, replace=0)).tolist()
     ...: new_numbers = np.random.randint(0,10, len(insertion_indices)).tolist()
     ...: out1 = np.insert(original_list, insertion_indices, new_numbers)
     ...: out2 = insert_numbers(original_list, insertion_indices, new_numbers)
     ...: print np.allclose(out1, out2)
True

In [185]: %timeit np.insert(original_list, insertion_indices, new_numbers)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.37 ms per loop

In [186]: %timeit insert_numbers(original_list, insertion_indices, new_numbers)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.8 ms per loop
```

Let's test out with arrays as inputs -

```
In [190]: original_list = np.arange(70000)
     ...: insertion_indices = np.sort(np.random.choice(len(original_list), 30000, replace=0))
     ...: new_numbers = np.random.randint(0,10, len(insertion_indices))
     ...: out1 = np.insert(original_list, insertion_indices, new_numbers)
     ...: out2 = insert_numbers(original_list, insertion_indices, new_numbers)
     ...: print np.allclose(out1, out2)
True

In [191]: %timeit np.insert(original_list, insertion_indices, new_numbers)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.48 ms per loop

In [192]: %timeit insert_numbers(original_list, insertion_indices, new_numbers)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 ms per loop
```

The performance just shoots up, because there's no runtime overhead on conversion to list.

Comment: That's a great answer!

Comment: Thanks for the two options! Performance is a concern, so the custom made function is awesome!

Answer (score 8):

Insert those values in backwards order. Like so:

```
original_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
insertion_indices = [1, 4, 5]
new_numbers = [8, 9, 10]

new = zip(insertion_indices, new_numbers)
new.sort(reverse=True)

for i, x in new:
    original_list.insert(i, x)
```

---

The reason this works is based on the following observation:

Inserting a value at the beginning of the `list` offsets the indexes of all other values by 1. Inserting a value at the end though, and the indexes remain unchanged. As a consequence, if you start by inserting the value with the largest index (`10`) and continue "backwards" you would not have to update any indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Increment the required index by 1 after every insert

```
original_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
insertion_indices = [1, 4, 5]
new_numbers = [8, 9, 10]

for i in range(len(insertion_indices)):
    original_list.insert(insertion_indices[i]+i,new_numbers[i])

print(original_list)
```

Output

```
[0, 8, 1, 2, 3, 9, 4, 10, 5, 6, 7]

#Required list
[0, 8, 1, 2, 3, 9, 4, 10, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this before your for loop:

```
for i in range(len(insertion_indices)):
    insertion_indices[i]+=i
```

Answer (score 0):

less elegant, but working too: use numpy ndarray, to increment indice each time:

```
import numpy as np

original_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
insertion_indices = [1, 4, 5]
new_numbers = [8, 9, 10]
pairs = np.array([[insertion_indices[i], new_numbers[i]] for i in range(len(insertion_indices))])

for pair in pairs:
    original_list.insert(pair[0], pair[1])
    pairs[:, 0] += 1
```